# Evitar volver atrás página php

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo un sistema de votaciones hecho en PHP y utilizando la librerìa mysql (sí, se que ya no se usa pero por problemas con el CMS y por tiempo debo implementarlo así). En la página validar.php decide si un asociado de una empresa ya votó (controlado con una columna val_voto que es tinyint) y si no lo ha hecho, le permite seleccionar de una lista o select de html. Una vez ha votado, se carga otra pàgina que confirma el voto y hace los UPDATES correspondientes (votar.php)

EL problema es que en esta pàgina (votar.php) si el asociado ya votò y vuelve hacia atrás en el navegador, puede votar nuevamente, lo cual es un error dado que sólo puede votar una vez y no ha valido ni funciones de javascript ni borrar la cachè de la página. Anexo los códigos en espera de que alguien me pueda ayudar dado que tengo que entregar este sistema y soy muy novato en php.

**valida.php**

```
<style type="text/css">
  label { color: black; font-family: Verdana; text-align: center;}

  .centrado{
    margin:10px auto;
    display:block;
    text-align: center;
    }
    H2 { color: black; font-family: Verdana; text-align: center;}

    input{
        color: black;
        font-family: Verdana;
      text-align: center;
    }
</style>
<script languaje="javascript">
    function funcion_javascript(){
        alert ("Estimado(a) asociado(a), su voto ya ha sido registrado o ha ingresado mal los datos, favor verif赤quelos e ingrese nuevamente.");
        location.href ="http://www.mipaginaweb.com";
    }
    function nodatos(){
        alert ("Los datos que han ingresado no son correctos, favor ingrese nuevamente");
        location.href ="http://www.mipaginaweb.com/inicio.php";
    }
    function voto(){
        alert ("Estimado(a) asociado(a), su voto ha sido registrado. Gracias por participar");
        location.href ="http://www.mipaginaweb.com";
    }
</script>
<div>
    <img class="centrado" src="logo.png" alt="">
    <h2>LISTADO DE CANDIDATOS A DELEGADOS DE SU ENTIDAD</h2>
</div>
```

PHP

```
    <?php
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    //conecta a la base de datos
    require 'bd.php';
    //se obtienen los datos de un formulario anterior
            $idasoc = $_POST['id'];
            $anio = $_POST['anio'];
            $mes = $_POST['mes'];
            $dia = $_POST['dia'];
            $fn = $anio."-".$mes."-".$dia;
    //consulta que valida si el votante ya votó (val_voto es un tinyint)
            $ver_voto= mysql_query("select val_voto from aa_asoc_votan_ent where id_asoc='".$idasoc."'",$serv);
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ver_voto);
            $var= $row['val_voto'];
    //Valida si la variable var es 'true' y si es asì alerta al asociado y se devuelve a la pàgina inicio.php
                if ($var == '')
                {
                    ?> <script languaje="javascript"> funcion_javascript(); </script> <?php
                }
    //si la variable var es 'false', carga el select
                else
                {
    //Obtiene un código de empresa para listar los candidatos disponibles
                    $consulta2 = mysql_query("SELECT cod_empresa FROM aa_asoc_votan_ent WHERE id_asoc='".$idasoc."'",$serv);
                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($consulta2))
                        {
                            $cod_ent = $row['cod_empresa'];
                        }
    //Consulta que obtiene el listado de los candidatos según la empresa y los carga en un select de html
                    $consulta3 = mysql_query("SELECT iddeleg, nombre FROM aa_delegados WHERE cod_empresa='".$cod_ent."'",$serv);
    ?>
                        <div class="centrado">
                            <form method='post' action='votar.php' id="form1">
                                <div>
                                    <select name="delegados" autocomplete="off">
                                        <option>Seleccione un delegado...</option>
                                        <?
                                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($consulta3))
                                            {
                                                echo "<option value=".$row['iddeleg'].">".$row['nombre']."</option>";
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Votar'onsubmit='voto()'>
<!--envía un input oculto con un valor de identificaciòn de asociado para comprobar en votar.php-->
                                    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($idasoc); ?>' >
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
    <?php
                    }
//si no hay datos de candidatos que pueda votar el asociado o son incorrectos.                    
                    else
                    {
                        if($filas ==0)
                        {
                            ?> <script languaje="javascript"> nodatos(); </script>
                        <?php
                        }
                    }
            }
```

votar.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
    Objeto=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(a=0;a<Objeto.length;a++){
        Objeto[a].onclick=function(){
            location.replace(this.href);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
javascript:window.history.forward(1);

function deshabilitaRetroceso(){
    window.location.hash="no-back-button";
    window.location.hash="Again-No-back-button" //chrome
    window.onhashchange=function(){window.location.hash="no-back-button";}
}

function voto(){
   alert ("Estimado(a) asociado(a), su voto ha sido registrado. Gracias por participar");
   location.href ="http://www.feser.com.co";
}
</script>

<html>

<?
require 'bd.php';
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
//trae datos de valida.php
    $idd = $_POST['id'];
    $votado = $_POST['delegados'];


    //Suma un voto al candidato 
        $consulta4 = mysql_query("UPDATE aa_delegados SET votos=votos+1 where cedula ='".$votado."'",$serv);
    //Establece valor de true a la columna val_voto, es decir que el asociado ya votó-
        $consulta5 = mysql_query("UPDATE aa_asoc_votan_ent SET valida_voto='true' where cedula ='".$cced."'",$serv);

    //si ya votó
    $variable = 'true';
    if ($variable){
    ?>
    <script languaje="javascript">
    voto();
    deshabilitaRetroceso();
    </script>
    <?
    }

    ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que el enfoque que estas tomando no es el mejor debido a que aunque logres que el usuario no **"vuelva a atras"** en el navegador puede pasar que cierre sesión, la vuelva a iniciar y vote nuevamente... Para que la **validación "perdure" durante el tiempo necesario de restricción del voto** necesitas manejarlo por base de datos.

Digamos que si el voto es diario. Deberías contar en tu base de datos con una **tabla** que almacene los **datos "temporales"** del usuario. La tabla por ejemplo podría tener los siguientes campos:

**1)** id_usuario (clave foranea proveniente de tu tabla de usuarios)

**2)** Fecha_votacion (para poder realizar comparacion)

**3)** Id_tema (sería clave foranea haciendo referencia al tema, motivo, nombre, articulo por el que votó)

**La clave primaria** podría ser un Id autoincremental o una combinación de los campos que mencione anteriormente o de algunos más que tu incluyas.

**Que tendrías que hacer?** Cuando el usuario ingrese y vote debes insertar en esta tabla de datos "temporales" el voto con el id del usuario y la fecha de votación (incluida la hora, tu ves si te conviene todo en un mismo campo o separado en dos campos)

Entonces cuando el usuario quiera presionar atras en el navegador e intente votar nuevamente tu tendrás la **validación** mediante un select a la base de datos que te traiga resultado si el usuario ya ha votado y que te haga una comparación de la fecha, si coincide la fecha del servidor (que debe estar actualizada) con la fecha registrada en la base de datos el usuario no podrá votar y evitas que vote "n" cantidad de veces en un día.

Esta idea es perfectamente amoldable para el caso de que sea el voto **semanal, mensual o anual** porque igual te basas en una fecha y en una comparación de esta fecha registrada con una de referencia elegida por ti para que el sistema valide.

Actualización:

Aquí esta un código de referencia para la comparación de fechas:

```
<?php
$fecha_actual = strtotime(date("d-m-Y H:i:00",time()));
$fecha_bd = strtotime($fecha_bd); // ejemplo 19-11-2008 21:00:00

if($fecha_actual == $fecha_bd){
        echo "Usted ya ha votado hoy, intente nuevamente mañana";
}else{
        // proceso de votación aquí
        // insert a la base de datos temporales con fecha incluida aquí
        echo "Usted ha votado por: ".$tema;
}
?>
```

Un saludo!

Comment: Hola, gracias por comentar. La votación es sólo en un día y el usuario sólo puede votar una sola vez. Para controlar cuántas veces votó utilizo un tinyint que sólo cambia 0 o 1 dependiendo si ya votó o no. Sólo necesito controlar que no pueda volver atrás pero no sirve el javascript. Tal vez guardando la hora en la que votó.

Comment: @reymagnus intento explicarte que eso de "prohibir" volver atrás en el navegador a un usuario es cercano a imposible... depende de muchos factores a tomar en cuenta, el navegador, el equipo con el que navegas (si es dispositivo móvil puede que tu diseño se vea y actúe diferente) etc

Comment: Y cómo validaría si ya votó a la fecha y hora actuales?

Comment: @reymagnus He actualizado la respuesta con el código para comparar las dos fechas y la validación como tal de si un usuario ya votó o no en el día. Espero te sea de utilidad. Un saludo!

Comment: @reymagnus Con la fecha también logras tener un histórico de cuando votó el usuario porque puede que no vote todos los días... quizás voto el lunes y sabado de la semana "x" por ejemplo. Eso te sirve para sacar datos estadisticos etc

Comment: Vale, la solución más sencilla me sirvió, puesto que apliqué controles en el código PHP para saber si campo de fecha y hora estaban NULL. Gracias Huskie por tu ayuda.

Comment: De nada @reymagnus. Me alegra que ya pudiste solucionar. Un saludo!